# Use Regression Model with non-scaled values (Partial Dependence Plot)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, model, regression

The model was fitted with scaled values (StandardScaler in sklearn).I want to display some graphics to explain the model output, but using the original scale values, because it would be more comprehensible.

For instance, the sklearn [Partial Dependence Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdQn7.png) unfortunally use scaled values on x-axis and it dificults to interpret the model.

Same when I plot [one feature x model output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSrnA.png) , but using the usual feature values.

In resume, It would be great to study the model behavior using non-scaled values. Maybe this question is not related to use model with non-scaled value, but how to scale x-axis in the plots, but I didn't achieve much.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I use sklearn pipeline to normalize the data.
So I don't need to normalize X_train directily:

```
pipe = Pipeline([('scaler', StandardScaler()), ('svr', svm.SVR(C=50, gamma=0.1, kernel='rbf'))])
pipe.fit (X_train, y_train)
```

So when I call Partial Dependency Plot:

```
display = PartialDependenceDisplay.from_estimator(
    pipe,
    x_train,
)
```

The graphics use X_train scale, but it still computes the StandardScaler!